Start a process in Jenkins without waiting for its end
I'm able to start a process in my Jenkins pipeline easily, but I'm struggling to avoid being blocked by the process.
Currently, Jenkins is waiting for its end before going on to the next step, but I need this process to be active during the whole build.
I tried with a lot of different ways, without success. Here a snippet:
Jenkins Pipeline:
stage ('Start process') {
    steps {
      script {
         powershell """
            try {
              . ${WORKSPACE}\\Scripts\\StartMyProcess.ps1 `
              -BuildID ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} `
              -BuildNumber ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} `
              -BuildVCSBranch ${GIT_BRANCH}
            } catch {
              Write-Error \$_
              exit 1
            }
            """
      }
    }
  }

PS1 File:
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $BuildId,
    [Parameter()]  [string] $BuildNumber,
    [Parameter()]  [string] $BuildVCSBranch
)
& "${PSScriptRoot}\MyBot.exe" `
    -MyBot `
    -BuildID $BuildID `
    -BuildNumber $BuildNumber `
    -BuildVCSBranch $BuildVCSBranch

Thank you in advance,
Luca

You can use parallel stages:
Documentation
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build'){
            failFast true
            parallel {
                stage('Start process') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                    steps {
                           script {
                               powershell """
                                  try {
                                   . ${WORKSPACE}\\Scripts\  \StartMyProcess.ps1 `
                                    -BuildID ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} `
                                    -BuildNumber ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} `
                                    -BuildVCSBranch ${GIT_BRANCH}
                                  } catch {
                                    Write-Error \$_
                                    exit 1
                                  }
                                  """
                            }
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Nested 1') {
                        steps {
                            echo "In stage Nested 1 within Branch C"
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Nested 2') {
                        steps {
                            echo "In stage Nested 2 within Branch C"
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        }
    }
}



You will also need to set more than one executor in your agent config.
Furthermore, you can do that in the dashboard → Build Executor Status → Built-In Node (if you use the build in node as your agent. Not recommended. Configure an agent, could be a vm or any machine) → Configure → Number of executors (set this to 2 or more. Preferably less than the number of vcpu you have) → save

Use PowerShell background jobs.
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    try {
      . ${WORKSPACE}\\Scripts\\StartMyProcess.ps1 `
      -BuildID ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} `
      -BuildNumber ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} `
      -BuildVCSBranch ${GIT_BRANCH}
    } catch {
      Write-Error \$_
      exit 1
    }
}

